# How to Maintain Bundle Extras between activities in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to pass data from login page to main activity which contains my menus which works fine. But the problem is that suppose a user clicks on a particular menu and open another activity lets say activity A. when the user press the go back button to switch to main activity the bundle gives a null pointer exception. Here is my login intent

```
    Bundle m=new Bundle();

    m.putString("userid",userid);

    Intent intent=new Intent(login.this,main.class);

    intent.putExtras(m);
    startActivity(intent);
    ///////////////
    main
        String userid;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
           {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
            }
```

Above code works fine but the problem arise when main activity creates another activity A. when Activity A want to go back to parent activity (main) activity gives a null pointer exception.

```
Intent inte=new Intent(A.this,main.class);
startActivity(inte);
```

Comment: from A to Main you dint put the bundle in intent...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()

Comment: Use Sentence case for class name. e.g MainActivity.class, Main.class etc

Comment: One suggestion you can use Shared preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not store the userid in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Setter:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("UserAccount", 0);
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("userid", userid); 
editor.commit();
```

Getter:

```
pref.getString("userid", "default_value");
```

Clear:

```
editor.remove("userid");
editor.commit();
```

Comment: thanks It work fine but suppose a user closes the application abruptly how do I clear SharedPreferences cache?

Comment: Try putting the clear commands into onDestroy() of your main activity. Else you can do session management using SharedPreferences - [Example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying access bundle when returning to Main Activity, but you dont create bundle in your intent. Check for it as follows,

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null)
{
  Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
}
```

Comment: @DavidJohns have already done that but I still need user id not be null I still need it to open other activities

Comment: Do you add bundle into your intent when navigating from another activity to Main Activity ?

Comment: I want to go back to the main activity without bundling back the extras again.

Comment: So, whats the problem then ? What happend when to navigate to Main without adding bundle ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the bundle in activity A then send the bundle to Activity A and when you are coming back from Activity A then call the intent with bundle to main activity again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, main.class);
i.putExtra("Key1", "ABC");
i.putExtra("Key2", "123");

// Starts main.class
startActivity(i);
```

Now in main.class

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras!=null){
     String a = extras.getString("Key1");
     String b = extras.getString("Key2");
}
```

Hope this will work..

Comment: I have already done that but I still want to use the userid to open other activities;

Comment: Then you have to again call the Activity with extras from Activity A